# Typescript | Interact with elements based on number/index value

Tags: typescript

Say you have an array that has already been previously saved:

```
blue pink orange gray green black purple white yellow red
```

Then you have 4 numbers printed on a page: `5`, `7`, `10`, `1`. They are all independent but have the same selector:

```
<p test-id='numbers'>
```

Each of those 4 numbers refers to the position of a colour in the array above. (eg. 5 = green).

You also have 4 randomly places buttons on the same page with a word on each one, but they are mixed up:

`blue` `red` `purple` and `green`

---

*The GOAL:*

**Click on the respective colour buttons in the correct order (1,5,7,10)**

*Question:*
How would you order the 4 numbers sequentially, then match the number to the index of the colours array? *So: 1, 5, 7, 10 = 0 (blue),4 (green), 6 (purple), 9(red)*

EDIT - adding what I attempted to do:

```
let arrayList = await (await colourArraySelector).getText()
let itemNumber = await (await numberSelector).getText()
let colourWord = await (await colourButtonSelector).getText()

arrayList.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(item, index);
  for (let num = 0; num < 4; num++) {
    if (index + 1) == itemNumber) {
    colourWord.click()
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: To make things easier, you might want to match colors to indices instead of indices to colors. You can then, on click for each color, check if the clicked index was the expected one (i.e. if the order is 5, 7, 10, 1, and I click button 5 already, it should expect me to click button 7).

Comment: Please limit this post to a single question.  If you have multiple questions you can make multiple posts.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue you are facing when pasted into a standalone IDE.  Right now there is no TypeScript code here.  Ideally you'd show an input/output requirement as well as any attempt you've made.

Comment: added an edit to the original post - hope that helps